# What does -o mean in an "if"?

Tags: bash, test

What is -o after -eq in the mentioned code:

...`[ $sorszam -eq 0 ] && min1=$ertek; [ $sorszam -eq 1 -o $sorszam -eq 2 -o $sorszam -eq 3 ] && [ $ertek -lt $min1 ] && min1=$ertek`...

Comment: Note that `-o` is considered obsolete, and the correct way to write *new* code would be to use `[ "$sorszam" -eq 1 ] || [ "$sorszam" -eq 2 ] || [ "$sorszam" -eq 3 ]` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in [the Linux Documentation Project page about *if*](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html), **-o** stands for the logical operator **OR**. In your case, the variable `sorszam` is checked whether it equals to 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Ah, so it is just an "or". Thanks the documentation, didn't know there was such thing.

Answer (score 2):

As you should know `[` is an equivalent to `test` built-in command.

```
$ help [
[: [ arg... ]
    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin...
```

so you should have a look at `help test | grep -- "-o "`:

```
EXPR1 -o EXPR2 True if either expr1 OR expr2 is true.
```

Answer (score 1):

`-eq` is an arithmetic binary operator that returns true if both numbers are equal.

`-o` is an or, you can can string it together with `-eq` to do multiple comparisons in one line.

[Source](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)